# Understanding Spring Repository Documentation

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm following the guide here to setup repositories on my site: http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories.introduction

I'm a little confused why in section 1.4.1 they all of the sudden extends `JpaRepository`... is this a JPA class or is this something they've written?  I tried to do the same thing in my application and it didn't work, it didn't know what JpaRepository is despite being loaded.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {
  // Declare query methods here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an interface hierarchy that you can extend either one of to make your interface being discovered as Spring Data repository. I didn't expect that to be needed to be documented as it's pretty obvious when opening the type and following the type hierarchy. I'll improve the documentation nevertheless. Here are your options:

- `Repository` - plain marker interface to allow the infrastructure to pick up repository interfaces
- `CrudRepository extends Repository` - adds CRUD methods
- `PagingAndSortingRepository extends CrudRepository` adds pagination and sorting functionality
- `$PersistenceTechnology$Repository extends PagingAndSortingRepository` - adds technology specific methods and method overrides to the interface. JPA redeclares `findAll()` to return a `List` instead of an `Iterable` etc.

Comment: I'm very new to Java and Spring both.  The other developer here was able to figure it out quickly, but it threw me for a loop because I wasn't sure how `JpaRepository` and some of the other classes fit into the picture since I wasn't familiar with them.  For someone who's newer, it would be very helpful if there was a link to a documentation page for that class.  I had trouble pulling it up in my JavaDoc.  That's just my wish list ^_^